# Loop Not Spending Value to Array in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When running this code it just prints out a blank array at the end:

```
[]
```

So why is it not appending either the value **a** or the value **b**?

```
import multiprocessing as mu

array_values=[]

def a(array):
    array.append('a')

def b(array):
    array.append('b')

def runInParallel(*fns):
    z=0
    while z<6:
        if __name__=='__main__':
            proc = []
            for fn in fns:
                p = mu.Process(target=fn,args=(array_values,))
                p.start()
                proc.append(p)
            for p in proc:
                p.join()
        z+=1

runInParallel(a,b)
print(array_values)
```

DESIRED FINAL OUTPUT OF FUNCTION:

```
['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't word is because [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.html) doesn't use shared memory.

You can use the following code to get your desired output (it uses [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/threading.html) which uses shared memory):

```py
import threading

array_values = []


def a(array):
    array.append('a')


def b(array):
    array.append('b')


def runInParallel(*fns):
    z = 0
    while z < 6:
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            proc = []
            for fn in fns:
                p = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=(array_values,))
                p.start()
                proc.append(p)
            for p in proc:
                p.join()
        z += 1


runInParallel(a, b)
print(array_values)
```

Comment: thank you! Also thanks for giving me the insight on shared memory and are there any more big differences between multiprocessing and threading?